# How to call same function for different conditions?

Tags: javascript

I m making another game by applying the Tetris game code. What I want to do is keep the box facing in the direction of the key that was pressed when I pressed the key.

```
function keydown(ev) {
  var handled = false;
  if (playing) {
    switch(ev.keyCode) {
      case KEY.LEFT:   actions.push(DIR.LEFT);  handled = true; break;
      case KEY.RIGHT:  actions.push(DIR.RIGHT); handled = true; break;
      case KEY.UP:     actions.push(DIR.UP);    handled = true; break;
      case KEY.DOWN:   actions.push(DIR.DOWN);  handled = true; break;
      case KEY.ESC:    lose();                  handled = true; break;
    }
  }
  else if (ev.keyCode == KEY.SPACE) {
    play();
    handled = true;
  }
  if (handled)
    ev.preventDefault();
}

// This is keydown function.
function handle(action) {
  switch(action) {
    case DIR.LEFT:  move(DIR.LEFT);  break;
    case DIR.RIGHT: move(DIR.RIGHT); break;
    case DIR.UP:    move(DIR.UP);    break;
    case DIR.DOWN:  move(DIR.DOWN);  break;
  }
}

function move(dir) {
  var x = current.x, y = current.y;
  switch(dir) {
    case DIR.RIGHT: x = x + 1; break;
    case DIR.LEFT:  x = x - 1; break;
    case DIR.DOWN:  y = y + 1; break;
    case DIR.UP:    y = y - 1; break;
  }
    current.x = x;
    current.y = y;
    invalidate();
    return true;


function drop() {
  if (move(DIR.DOWN)) {
    dropPiece();
    }
  else(move(DIR.LEFT))
    dropPiece();
  }


// If game is playing, function drop() is activated. I tried to figure out how to do 
// what I wanted. But run this function, result only move(DIR.DOWN)!! What am i suppose to do?
function dropPiece() {
  eachblock(current.type, current.x, current.y, current.dir, function(x, y) {
    setBlock(x, y, current.type);
  });
}
// I want to call function dropPiece() when i press the key!!
```

Comment: I wanted to run your code but it's not possible because the code is not complete. Maybe you can post the full code.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what's going on, but please replace all those `switch` statements with something more sensible. E.g. your `handle` function could be simply `function handle(action) { move(action); }` or is obsolete all together

Comment: I find `drop()` you use `else(move(DIR.LEFT))` instead `else if (move(DIR.LEFT))`